# What template needs to be added in regular expression post processor in Jmeter for the following condition

Tags: jmeter

Regular Expression -"p_instance" value="(.*?)"
Match count: 1
Match[1][0]="p_instance" value="11917272245034"
Match[1][1]=11917272245034

When added $1$ in template - error is displayed(request is not created)
$1$$1$ is dding duplicate strings in the request. 
What should be the template to fetch this value

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to your Test Plan - this way you will be able to see all the variables generated by the Regular Expression Extractor in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details.

Going forward when asking for a help with the regular expressions include essential part of the response and indicate which value you are looking for.

---

Here comes mandatory advice [not to use regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) and suggestion to use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Regular expression is fetching right value as per debug sampler.In my case I have added two regex post processors against same request  1- for instance  and other for submission id.In request $1$ is fetching correct submission id but same in other regular expression is throwing error.                                                                                       response : <input type="hidden" <input type="hidden" name="p_instance" value="9632060963329" id="pInstance" /><input type="hidden" name="p_page_submission_id" value="25520241278137" id="pPageSubmissionId" />